# Find and replace SSH command?

Tags: sed

hello I am needing help to be able to replace a line of a file with ssh and sed.

The problem is the following I have a string for example:

mystring = 1234

The point is that after the = it is not always 1234, so I am not able to replace that line.

```
sed -i 's/mystring =/mystring=1234/g' file.ini
```

when I run it two things happen:

1. mystring = 12341234 (add the numbers)
2. mystring = 123412345 (don't delete it, leave it there)

and if the variable  `(sed -i 's/mystring=/mystring=1234/g' file.ini)`  is executed more than twice, what it does is add the number at the end.

That is why I need to replace the entire line, something that if it is done more than 1 you see it will always remain the same, and if it is different, change it to the value that is set in the command.

From already thank you very much.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Hello good day, the problem is described and with the examples that pass me, what else do you need?

Comment: What do you want to do? Replace a line starting with mystring with a different line? `s/^mystring =.*/your new line content/`. I don't see how "numbers are appended"? Or "I cannot replace, because the end is different". Please clarify

Comment: Well, if after the (mystring =) there are numbers, what I put was as an example, you can replace $var with a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always match and replace the whole line:

```
sed -i 's/^mystring=.*/mystring=newvalue/' yourfile
```

`.*` in a regular expression matching any number of characters, including none.

You can also `c`hange all lines containing a certain pattern:

```
sed -i '/^mystring=/c\
mystring=newvalue' yourfile
```

Or with GNU sed:

```
sed -ie '/^mystring=/c\' -e 'mystring=newvalue' yourfile
```